# iCloud data storage deletion

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud

Is there a way to permanently erase all the data on iCloud or some category, or once stored is the data always available on iCloud, with no option to delete permanently?

Answer (score 1):

### On iOS

You can go to **Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage**. You can then select an app that you wish to remove iCloud data for, tap Edit, then delete the data that you no longer need on iCloud.
(Some apps only have a Documents & Data section - this means that it will remove *all* data from iCloud, without any option of selecting individual files.)

[image: iCloud on iOS]

### On Mac

You can go to **~/Library/Mobile Documents** and delete individual apps/files there.

[image: iCloud on Mac]